# Disable ui.TextInput in nextcord

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, nextcord

I have TextInput in modal, and I want to disable it. How can I do this?

```
self.primer = nextcord.ui.TextInput(
                label="Пример",
                min_length=1,
                max_length=50,
                style=nextcord.TextInputStyle.paragraph,
                default_value=self.primer_value,
            )
```

Will be thankful for any help. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you cant :( `TextInput`s arent something you can disable.

for now it isn't in [discord's roadmap](https://github.com/discord/discord-api-docs/discussions/3581), but you always can suggest new things at [discord api docs github repo's discussion page](https://github.com/discord/discord-api-docs/discussions)!

correct me if i was wrong.